Problem Running Trivy with Custom Policies on Terraform Configurations
I'm trying to run Trivy with custom Rego policies to check my Terraform configuration. However, my custom policy doesn't seem to be applied correctly as I don't see any messages in the output.
Command Used
trivy config --skip-check-update --config-policy ./custom_policies.rego --policy-namespaces custom.rules project/

custom_policies.rego
package custom.rules

# Check upgrade minor version in RDS Amazon RDS
deny[msg] {
    input.resource_type == "aws_db_instance"
    not input.auto_minor_version_upgrade
    msg := sprintf("RDS instance '%s' doesn't have automatic minor version upgrade enabled.", [input.db_instance_identifier])
}

project/main.tf
resource "aws_db_instance" "example" {
  allocated_storage             = 20
  storage_type                  = "gp2"
  engine                        = "mysql"
  engine_version                = "8.0"
  instance_class                = "db.t2.micro"
  username                      = "foo"
  password                      = "bar"
  db_subnet_group_name          = "my_subnet_group"
  parameter_group_name          = "default.mysql5.7"
  skip_final_snapshot           = true
  publicly_accessible           = false
  auto_minor_version_upgrade    = false  
}

Problem
After running the command, I don't see the expected message about my custom policy. I was expecting a message saying that the RDS instance doesn't have automatic minor version upgrade enabled, but there is no such output.
Additional Details

Trivy version: 0.51.1

What I've Tried

Ensured that the paths to the Rego policy and the Terraform configuration are correct.
Verified that the Rego policy syntax is correct.

Question
What could be the reason my custom policy is not being applied correctly? How can I debug this issue and ensure my policy is checked against the Terraform configuration?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
